# Is there a way to make Ruby CSV gem generate CSVs with Windows (CR LF) End Of Lines?

Tags: ruby, windows, csv, rubygems, eol

For some reason CSV gem is generating CSVs with Unix EOL (see screenshot) here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4re7tpp4pj9psov/ice_screenshot_20171230-162304.png?dl=0
Screenshot made in Notepad++ (View all Characters)

Code I use:

```
require 'csv'

all_the_things = []

all_the_things << ["item1.1","item1.2","item1.3"]
all_the_things << ["item2.1","item2.1","item2.1"]
all_the_things << ["item3.1","item3.1","item3.1"]

CSV.open("test.csv", "wb" ) do |row|
  row << ["Column1", "Column2", "Column3"] #just headers
    all_the_things.each do |data|
      row << data
    end
end
```

Is there a way to make it use Windows EOL (CR LF) instead of UNIX (LF) ones ?

I'm using Windows 10, and if I just output some lines to file using puts everything working just fine (albeight managing proper data structure without CSV gem is nightmare):

```
....
   File.open("test.csv", "w") do |line|
    myarray.each do |data|
      line.puts data
    end
end
```

Thank you in advance for any ideas and Happy New Year !

Comment: What is “Ruby CSV gem”?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it is clearly stated [in the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new), one might use the `row_sep` option to specify the row separator:

```
require 'csv'
#                               ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ here
CSV.open("/tmp/file.csv", "wb", row_sep: "\r\n") do |csv|
  csv << %w|1 2 3 4|
  csv << %w|a b c d|
end
```

Also, there is no “CSV gem,” it’s ruby standard library.

Comment: `csv` is both. [Since 2.5 it's a so-called default gem.](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_5_0/NEWS#stdlib-compatibility-issues-excluding-feature-bug-fixes)